# using onClick in react to open new window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a table with "name_book" and "book_type" and "book_price" .

what I want is to enable the user to get more information about the book by "Clicking" on the "name_book" which should open a new tap for them .

I'm using react and most of the thing I find includes html which I don't use .

I tried doing `onClick: (name_book) => window.open("Link")` which didn't work .

Comment: please show some more of your code so we can help you debug

Comment: What is the `Link`?